# Android SQLite - Primary Key Desc

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key, descendant

First create the id generator:

```
private int generateId() {
       // if the table is empty returns -1
       int result = -1;
       String sql = "SELECT id FROM table order by id asc";
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
       //if any id is decremented
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        result = (cursor.getInt(0) -1);
       cursor.close();
       db.close();
       return result;
    }
```

this will be our initial value
we can replace it with another value

```
 // if the table is empty returns -1
 int result = -1;
```

---

then use it in the insert:

```
public void add(Type type) {
        int id = this.generateId();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("id", id);
        cv.put("value",type.value)
        ...
        db.insert(table, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        db.close();
    }
```

Does anyone have another solution?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do we need to guess the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening/closing the database twice is inefficient; and there is a [helper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) to read a single value from a query.

Anyway, you could move the computations into SQL:

```java
db = getWritableDatabase();
try {
    long id = DBUtils.longForQuery(db,
                    "SELECT IFNULL(MIN(id) - 1, 0) FROM MyTable", null);
    cv.put("id", id);
    ...
} finally {
    db.close();
}
```